MediaWiki Block Quote With Two Paragraphs Loses Spacing
I'm pretty new to MediaWiki and formatting. I have a problem that's fairly simple but causes me nearly endless frustration, and I can't seem to find anything about it online. I've tried on numerous occasions for months.
When I create or edit an article using the Visual Editor I will often try to add something I pulled from elsewhere into a block quote. This works great if the content consists of 1 line, 3 lines, 4 lines, 5 lines, etc...
However, for a quote which occupies exactly 2 lines I end up with a strange situation where the two lines merge together into a single line. Even though there is (or was) a line in between them.
I can temporarily get around the problem if I add an empty line above or below the two lines (hence making it effectively 3 lines). That works for me, as long as I remember every time, but this is hardly a solution for a wiki that I'm hoping to eventually build a community around.
I put a link to a page that provides an example from my wiki:
https://quadrigainitiative.com/cryptocurrencyhackscamfraudwiki/index.php?title=Paragraph_Spacing_Issue&venotify=created
I have no idea where to turn to for a solution, so hopefully someone here may have some idea of what's going on.

Please copy the text here to make a [mre].

This mediawiki page with the problem is Paragraph Spacing Issue. To fix the problem of losing line spaces, both the opening blockquote and the closing blockquote need to be on separate lines with the content in between. Doing so produces consistent spacing for any x lines where x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 . . .}
This is the current source content for the page, omitting some of the explanatory nowiki tagged explanations:
If I create one line of quotes, everything is fine:<blockquote>This shows up fine since it's one line.</blockquote>If I create three lines of quotes, it's also fine:<blockquote>This is the first line.

This is the second line.

This is the third line.</blockquote>However, if I attempt to have exactly two lines in the quote box, then it breaks and things merge together into a single line.<blockquote>See this first line.

Will get merged into the second line.</blockquote>...Even if I  manually edit the source and insert a <nowiki><br></nowiki>, the paragraphs still show up with different spacing than expected.<blockquote>This is a test line.<br>This is a second test line.</blockquote>Compare with a three line quote:<blockquote>This is a test line.

This is a second test line.

This is a third test line.</blockquote>

Consistently format the source so that the blockquote tags are on their own lines. So, to summarize, and omitting some of the explanatory content from OP's wiki:
<blockquote>
This shows up fine since it's one line.  
</blockquote>
    
If I create three lines of quotes, it's also fine:
  
<blockquote>
This is the first line.  
  
This is the second line.  
  
This is the third line.  
</blockquote>
    
However, if I attempt to have exactly two lines in the quote box, then it
breaks and things merge together into a single line.
    
<blockquote>
See this first line.  
  
Will get merged into the second line.  
</blockquote>

Wiki syntax (also called Wiki markup by Mediawiki) is slightly different that SO markup. It also seems to get rendered slightly differently. I DID test the code snippet above in my sandbox in Wikipedia, and got the desired results.

Thanks for trying to help. The  does add a space between the lines, however it's a different smaller space than normally occurs, and this has the disadvantage of requiring the editor to go and manually modify the source code, which is at least inconvenient, and potentially impractically confusing.

Adding  is the same disadvantage, and a really long gap instead of short.

Fundamentally, with 3 or more lines each paragraph of the text is surrounded by  tags at the HTML level, while with 1 or 2 lines the whole text entirely is surrounded by a single  tag. This works for 1 line, but doesn't work for 2. The  tag is totally different from the  tag, so it looks different in the browser.

@azoundria Thank you for explaining what you wanted more clearly in your wiki and these helpful comments here!  I totally revised my answer and tested it. This works on my English Wikipedia sandbox, so it should for your Mediawiki install too.

Thanks so much for all your help. While I understand from the wiki syntax what it needs to look like and I can manually (in the wikitext editor) get this kind of output, the main issue is that the visual editor does not generate this kind of wikitext by default from typing text on two separate lines. It seems like that is the primary source of the issue at the moment.
